# How to correctly get the clicked element after adding addEventListener with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a calculator-like screen using JavaScript. I created the number pad buttons using the following HTML template

```
<button type="button" class="calulator_button" data-default-value="{NUMBER_VALUE}">
    <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0">
        <p class="card-text display-4">{NUMBER_VALUE}</p>
    </div>
</button>
```

When the button that has the class `calulator_button` is clicked, I want to add the `data-default-value` to the display screen.

I created the following JS code which listens for a click event on the `button.calulator_button` selector and fires `appendNumberToCalulator` function.

Currently, I am using `event.target` to find the clicked element to determine the `data-default-value` attribute.

**Problem**

Depending where the user clicks on the button, the `event.target` may return different result.

For example, if the user clicks on the number inside the button directly, the `event.target` returns the `<p>1</p>` element inside the button. If the user clicks little further than the number, the `<div></div>` wrapping the `<p></p>` element is returned. Finally, if the user clicks around the edge of the button "just outside the `<div></div>` element", the actual button is returned.

**Question**

How can I ensure that the button element is returned regardless of where the user clicks?

Here is the complete snippet

```js
var calulatorButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button.calulator_button');
for (var i = 0; i < calulatorButtons.length; i++) {
    calulatorButtons[i].addEventListener('click', appendNumberToCalulator);
}

function getCalculatorDisplayElement() {
    return document.getElementById('Calculator_Total');
}

function appendNumberToCalulator(event) {

    var valueToAppend = event.target.getAttribute('data-default-value');
    var totalDisplay = getCalculatorDisplayElement();

    if (valueToAppend == '.' && totalDisplay.value.indexOf('.') > -1) {

        return;
    }

    totalDisplay.value += valueToAppend;
}


/* Handle Clear Screen */
document.getElementById('Calulator_Clear').addEventListener('click', function (_event) {
    getCalculatorDisplayElement().value = '';
});


/* Handle Clear Backspace */
document.getElementById('Calulator_Backspace').addEventListener('click', function (_event) {
    var value = getCalculatorDisplayElement().value;
    if (!value) {
        return;
    }
    getCalculatorDisplayElement().value = value.slice(0, -1);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                
    <div class="form-row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-8">
            <label class="sr-only" for="Calculator_Total"></label>
            
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" id="Calculator_Total" name="Calculator_Total" type="text" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100" id="Calulator_Backspace">«</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100" id="Calulator_Clear">C</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-deck mr-0 ml-0">
        

        <button type="button" data-action-type="Calculator" class="card text-white bg-secondary text-center calulator_button" style="min-width: 32%; max-width: 32.5%" data-id="" data-default-value="1">
            <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0">
                <p class="card-text display-4">1</p>
            </div>
        </button>


        <button type="button" data-action-type="Calculator" class="card text-white bg-secondary text-center calulator_button" style="min-width: 32%; max-width: 32.5%" data-id="" data-default-value="2">
            <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0">
                <p class="card-text display-4">2</p>
            </div>
        </button>


        <button type="button" data-action-type="Calculator" class="card text-white bg-secondary text-center calulator_button" style="min-width: 32%; max-width: 32.5%" data-id="" data-default-value="3">
            <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0">
                <p class="card-text display-4">3</p>
            </div>
        </button>


        <button type="button" data-action-type="Calculator" class="card text-white bg-secondary text-center calulator_button" style="min-width: 32%; max-width: 32.5%" data-id="" data-default-value="4">
            <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0">
                <p class="card-text display-4">4</p>
            </div>
        </button>


        <button type="button" data-action-type="Calculator" class="card text-white bg-secondary text-center calulator_button" style="min-width: 32%; max-width: 32.5%" data-id="" data-default-value="5">
            <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0">
                <p class="card-text display-4">5</p>
            </div>
        </button>


        <button type="button" data-action-type="Calculator" class="card text-white bg-secondary text-center calulator_button" style="min-width: 32%; max-width: 32.5%" data-id="" data-default-value="6">
            <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0" >
                <p class="card-text display-4">6</p>
            </div>
        </button>


        <button type="button" data-action-type="Calculator" class="card text-white bg-secondary text-center calulator_button" style="min-width: 32%; max-width: 32.5%" data-id="" data-default-value="7">
            <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0">
                <p class="card-text display-4">7</p>
            </div>
        </button>


        <button type="button" data-action-type="Calculator" class="card text-white bg-secondary text-center calulator_button" style="min-width: 32%; max-width: 32.5%" data-id="" data-default-value="8">
            <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0">
                <p class="card-text display-4">8</p>
            </div>
        </button>


        <button type="button" data-action-type="Calculator" class="card text-white bg-secondary text-center calulator_button" style="min-width: 32%; max-width: 32.5%" data-id="" data-default-value="9">
            <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0">
                <p class="card-text display-4">9</p>
            </div>
        </button>


        <button type="button" data-action-type="Calculator" class="card text-white bg-secondary text-center calulator_button" style="min-width: 32%; max-width: 32.5%" data-id="" data-default-value="00">
            <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0">
                <p class="card-text display-4">00</p>
            </div>
        </button>


        <button type="button" data-action-type="Calculator" class="card text-white bg-secondary text-center calulator_button" style="min-width: 32%; max-width: 32.5%" data-id="" data-default-value="0">
            <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0">
                <p class="card-text display-4">0</p>
            </div>
        </button>


        <button type="button" data-action-type="Calculator" class="card text-white bg-secondary text-center calulator_button" style="min-width: 32%; max-width: 32.5%" data-id="" data-default-value=".">
            <div class="card-body pl-0 pr-0">
                <p class="card-text display-4">.</p>
            </div>
        </button>

    </div>
```

Comment: use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler), it will refer to the element the button that raised the event: `var valueToAppend = this.dataset.defaultValue;` (use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) to get the `data-` attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) property, rather than `target`. The introduction to the linked MDN article explains the difference, and why you want `currentTarget` in this case, better than I can.